# Azure Pipeline - Publish Maven Artifacts Without Comitting to Repository

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

New to Azure in general so sorry if my question isn't as concise as it should be.

**What I'm trying to do:** When someone pushes to master I want the pipeline to bump the project version and release it as an artifact that is available in the *Artifacts* tab. This shouldn't create any additional commits.

**What I've tried:** To verify that my local connection to Artifacts was working I tried **mvn deploy** which worked fine but it doesn't handle version bumping automatically, so instead I tried switching over to

```
mvn -B release:prepare release:perform
```

As it does take care of bumping but this creates other issues as it commits two additional times to git instead of amending itself onto the head and I need to tinker with soft resets and force push to get it correct. Also not sure if it does release to Artifacts as I had issues getting git credentials working...

Is there a way for the pipeline to look at what Artifacts has already been released and just bump based on that so it doesn't have to commit anything to the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after a lot of days I finally got it workig. **Releasing artifacts without committing code to repo using organization feeds**

```
trigger:
  - main

pr: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - name: artifactVersion
  - name: organization
    value: '<organization>'
  - name: feedName
    value: '<feedName>'

steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Fetching latest version of artifact
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        
        # Get list over packages
        $url = 'https://feeds.dev.azure.com/$(organization)/_apis/packaging/Feeds/$(feedName)/packages?api-version=6.0-preview.1'
        $pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

        # Find our artifact in the feed over all artifacts
        $packageName = echo '${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}' | mvn -N -q -DforceStdout help:evaluate
        echo "Looking for artifact versions for packageName: $packageName"
        $packageId = ''
        Foreach ($package IN $pipeline.value) {
          if($package.name -eq $packageName) {
            $packageId = $package.id
          }
        }
        if($packageId -eq '') {
          echo "No artifact found, assuming this is first release"
          $artifactVersion = 1
        } else {
          $url = 'https://feeds.dev.azure.com/$(organization)/_apis/packaging/Feeds/$(feedName)/Packages/' + $packageId + '/versions?api-version=6.0-preview.1'
          $pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
        
          # Find latest version of the artifact
          Foreach ($package IN $pipeline.value) {
            if($package.isLatest) {
              $artifactVersion = [int]$package.version+1
            }
          }
        }
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=artifactVersion]$artifactVersion"
        echo "Preparing release for artifaction version: $artifactVersion"
    env:
      SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
    inputs:
      artifactsFeeds: '$(feedName)'
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: Preparing artifact
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |

        echo "Artifact version to be released: $(artifactVersion)"
        $userNameOfHead = git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an'
        $userEmailOfHead = git log -1 --pretty=format:'%ae'
        git config --global user.email "$userNameOfHead"
        git config --global user.name "$userEmailOfHead"

        mvn -B -DreleaseVersion="$(artifactVersion)" release:prepare release:perform
```

pom.xml changes needed:

```
...
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>                
   <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.3</version>
   <configuration>
      <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
      <localCheckout>true</localCheckout>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
...
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
      <id><id></id>
      <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/<organization>/_packaging/<feedName>/maven/v1</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<scm>
   <developerConnection>
      scm:git:git@github.com:<repo>
   </developerConnection>
</scm>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Artifacts which's on the left-hand menu is designed to be consumed as shared modules, which is for custom packages instead of publish build artifacts. For the Build artifacts, you might check specific pipeline(which finished run) → "Summary" → "Related", and you can see what pipeline published.

I don't know if I misunderstand your question, and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66568858/how-to-show-pipeline-artifact-in-the-artifacts-section-in-azure-devops) might help you get some idea.

Comment: Hmm, kinda. I don't want it to submit the bumped version into the repository. I think I have a solution in the work that doesn't touch the repo and just creates the artifact on its own. The git stuff in the answer was great though as I hadn't fixed that yet

Comment: I submitted an answer myself, please have a look if you have time :)